# CKEditor not working after Ajax call

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor as a wysiwyg editor. My page has some form elements on them which are loaded through an Ajax call. When i fill in all the data including the wysiwyg editor and then hit the Save button nothing is saved. The submitting is also done through an Ajax call.

Nothing is saved because CKEditor isn't updating the original `textarea` properly. I found an answer that said to do the following **before** the submit:

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    console.log(instanceName);
    CKEDITOR.instances['element[1][content]'].updateElement();
}
```

This is triggered everytime before i submit my form. But this code still doesn't update the real textarea with the content that the CKEditor has...

Anyone any idea how i can solve this problem?

I'm using the latest CKEditor *(3.6.5, released on 10 October 2012)*.

### Edit

Just noticed through the console of Firefox that `updateElement()` is undefined when i run the following command:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['element[1][content]'].updateElement();
```

But when i run this, then it does return an object:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['element[1][content]'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is bad. Why do you use a loop when you call the method on the same object? This one is better:

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[ instanceName ].updateElement();
}
```

If something's still wrong, please share the code that you use for creating editors. Perhaps your textareas are incorrectly associated with editor instances.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually have that exact same code. Eventually i tried to hardcode the element name in there to see if it made a difference. But forgot to put my original code back when posting my question here. So both methods failed for me.

Comment: Most likely you try to call it in a wrong moment or something's wrong with editor itself. Can you post an inspected content of ``CKEDITOR.instances['element[1][content]'];`` ?

Comment: Well that returns a very large object. I do see the `updateElement()` function in there, but calling that function returns `undefined` for some weird reason. I'm now using `getData()` instead to get the content from the CKEditor and then i manually set it back in the corresponding textarea. That seems to be a good work around.

Answer (score 1):

There is alternate solution, where you can add data in ckeditor without edit value of instance.

e.g.

in Script part in View:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#editBasic").click(function(){
        url = "<?=$this->webroot?>derivedItineraries/getDetail/<?=$derived_itinerary_id?>";
        var div = '#basic_detail';
        var data = {id: 1};
        callajax(url, data, $(div));
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

In Ajax Calling function:

```
function callajax2(url, data, divname){
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : url,
        dataType : 'text',
        data: data,

        success: function(data) {
            divname.text('');
            divname.append(data);
            divname.show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                 divname.show(500);
        }
});
return false;
```

}

In Controller Page:

```
public function getDetail($id = null) {
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');
       $this->viewClass = 'Json';

       $this->loadModel('Destination');

        $this->DerivedItinerary->recursive = -1;
        $derivedItineraries = $this->DerivedItinerary->findById($id);

        $destination_covered = $this->destination_covered($id);
        $destinations = $this->Destination->find('list');

        $arrData=array(
            'itinerary'=>$derivedItineraries,
            'destination_covered' => $destination_covered,
            'destinations' => $destinations
        );
        $this->set('data', $arrData);
        $this->render('derived_basic', 'ajax'); 
}
```

There should be file in View, named "ControllerName"/json/derived_basic.ctp

file content in "derived_itineraries/json/derived_basic.ctp":

```
<?php
 echo $this->Html->script('/ckeditor/ckeditor', false);
  echo $this->Form->create();
  echo $this->Form->input('inclusion', array('type'=>'textarea', 'class'=>'ckeditor', 'required'=>'true', 'div'=>'required', 'style'=>'width:200px;', 'value'=> "Test data"))."      </td></tr>";
  echo $this->Form->end();
 ?>
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `done()` and `then()` methods after ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url
}).done(function(data){
     $('#content').html(data);
}).then(function(){
     //create ckeditor
});
```